# How to delete objects with gsutils following a wildcard pattern?

Tags: cmd, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

We can run a [gsutils command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm) to delete objects as follows:

```
gsutil rm -a gs://bucket/**
```

Now I would like to only remove certain folders following a wildcard pattern:

```
gs://bucket/folder/{WILDCARD-A}/folderA/{WILDCARD-B}/folderB
```

The idea is to delete all files with target folder B.

How can this be achieved with gsutils?

Comment: Have you tried gsutil `rm -r gs://bucket/folder/{WILDCARD-A}/folderA/{WILDCARD-B}/folderB` applying your [wildcat patterns](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#efficiency-consideration:-using-wildcards-over-many-objects)? If you want to bulk delete a hundred thousand or more objects, avoid using `gsutil`, as the process takes a long time to complete.

Comment: What is the alternative to remove objects?

Comment: @JohnAndrews Based on the context of your original question, that specific inquiry will require a new posted question as per Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: (@OsvaldoLópez: `wildcat`?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question - please read the tag wiki of [tag:google-cloud-storage]

Comment: @pppery Disagree, gsutil is a command line tool, widely used, and certainly programming related. See also https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gsutil rm -r gs://bucket/folder/{WILDCARD-A}/folderA/{WILDCARD-B}/folderB` applying your [wildcard patterns](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#efficiency-consideration:-using-wildcards-over-many-objects). If you have a large number of objects to remove, use the `gsutil -m` option, which enables multi-threading/multi-processing. In case you need to [bulk delete](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#delete-objects-in-bulk) a hundred thousand or more objects, avoid using `gsutil`, as the process takes a long time to complete. Instead use the Google Cloud console, which can delete up to several million objects, or [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle), which can delete any number of objects.

Comment: Was this answer useful?

Comment: This solved it. Basically I put * for every place in the pattern where a wildcard was needed. There are some notes on the performance, as also outlined in the link you provided.