# How to delete specific sub directory with wildcard gsutil?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72364345/how-to-delete-objects-with-gsutils-following-a-wildcard-pattern) i am trying to delete specific folders from my bucket using wildcard in a `gsutil` command such as :

```
gsutil rm -r gs://bucket-name/path/to/**/content
```

or

```
gsutil rm -r gs://bucket-name/path/to/*/content
```

This is throwing the error :

```
zsh: no matches found: gs://bucket-name/path/to/**/content
zsh: no matches found: gs://bucket-name/path/to/*/content
```

Where the `*` or `**` is replacing IDs (thousands of records) and under each there are 2 directories : `content`, `content2` and i only want to remove the `content` directory

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083114/18265570) by @Mike Schwartz, You have to use single or double quotes while using wildcards.

> zsh is attempting to expand the wildcard before `gsutil` sees it (and is complaining that you have no local files matching that wildcard). Please try this, to prevent zsh from doing so:
>
> ```
> gsutil rm 'gs://bucket/**'
> ```